# Generating XML with DBMS_XMLGEN even if resultset is empty

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I'm using DBMS_XMLGEN to create an XML from a given query. I format this XML using an XSLT.

I encounter a problem when the result set is empty: the XML returned by DBMS_XMLGen.getXML is empty (no empty XML nodes - just a 0-sized clob).
I need the XML to retain the same structure as defined in the XSLT, but simply return empty XML nodes.

This is the code (lv_FinalQuery and lv_Clb_Xsl are calculated prior to this)

```
       -- creating new context query
       lv_Vc2_location := 'DBMS_XMLGEN.newContext';
       lv_queryCtx := DBMS_XMLGen.newContext(lv_FinalQuery);

       -- Setting the xsl file with the query context
       lv_Vc2_location := 'DBMS_XMLGEN.setXSLT';
       DBMS_XMLGen.setXSLT(lv_queryCtx,lv_Clb_Xsl);

       -- Setting the rowset tag
       lv_Vc2_location := 'DBMS_XMLGEN.setRowsetTag';
       DBMS_XMLGen.setRowsetTag(lv_queryCtx, 'USER_LIST');

       -- Setting the row tag
       lv_Vc2_location := 'DBMS_XMLGEN.setRowTag';
       DBMS_XMLGen.setRowTag(lv_queryCtx, 'USER');

       -- Getting the xml
       lv_Vc2_location := 'DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML';
       p_XmlResult := DBMS_XMLGen.getXML(lv_queryCtx);
```

Comment: May be you can try to add nvl() to your values.Example, nvl(L_USER,'')

Comment: Thanks, Ahamed, that would have been to much work as there are a lot of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up simply returning a prebuilt XML if the output of DBMS_XMLGen.getXML is null:

```
   IF p_XmlResult IS NULL THEN
        p_XmlResult := '<USER_LIST>the rest of the XSLT structure is here...</USER_LIST>';
   END IF;
```